# Wrap text content inside a clip path polygon(triangle) shape and image clipped on other half

Tags: html, css, image, word-wrap, clip-path

Im trying to achieve something like this
[image]

I need to display some text and an image in two halves like shown in the above image.
Tried to use clip-path ,but the text content is not wrapped and have issues with alignment too.

My code:

```css
.clipped-text{
  width: 250px; height: 250px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 0 0);
  text-align: justify;
  position: absolute;

}

.clipped-image{
  width: 250px; height: 250px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
  text-align: justify;
   position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<div>
 <img class="clipped-image" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png"/>
 <p class="clipped-text">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need shape-outside here:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  text-align: justify;
}

.clipped-image {
  float:right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1e90ff;
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
  clip-path:     polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img class="clipped-image" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" />
  <p class="clipped-text">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
</div>
```

You can reduce the code like below:

```css
.clipped-text  {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  text-align: justify;
}

.clipped-text:before {
  content:"";
  float:right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1069/400/400) center/cover;
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
  clip-path:     polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<p class="clipped-text">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
```